# Made huge mistake when updating, nothing seems to work

Tags: 12.04, updates

I recently tried to update my old song laptop to 12.4 to make it more useable, but I accidentally closed the computer without thinking while it was installing packages. Now I've turned it back on and all I get is a black screen with a line of settings - file, edit,view, go, bookmarks, help. I can't connect to the internet, the only thing I can do is change the background colour from black to blue or purple. I'm not very tech savvy so please use fairly simple language. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to get access to a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1.  If it works, log in and try the following commands to continue an interrupted update:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you don't have Internet, here's something else you can try:

First, boot an Ubuntu live CD and click the "Try Ubuntu" option.  When you get to a desktop, connect to a wifi network.  Then open a terminal and type:

```
sudo mount /dev/<sdaX> /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo chroot /mnt

apt-get update

apt-get upgrade
```

**Note that instead of /dev/sdaX in the first command, type whatever partition Ubuntu is installed in.  If you don't know, install gparted from the software center, open it, and figure it out from the partition sizes.**

If nothing works and you just want to back up and reinstall, then from the Live CD session open the file browser, and on the left hand side you should be able to see your hard disk and access all your files.  From there, you can copy your home folder to a flash drive/external HDD.

Comment: It says to enter a sudo password, but I don't think I have one... What do I do?

Comment: @user270189 your sudo password is the same as your account password.

Comment: Wait, no. I just did the update command but some index files failed to download and have been ignored. Should I repeat the command?

Comment: @user270189 I would suggest that you proceed with the upgrade command, and post back if you still encounter problems.  At this point it seems like the failed index files may be an unrelated issue.

Comment: I did that, but it says 'need to get 4.9.1/849 MB of archives and asks to free 27.5 MB of dusk space, I responded yes and it said to use apt-update. I tried it again and it just went through the same thing. Is this a disk problem? Memory trouble?

Comment: Is this computer normally connected to the internet with a wired connection, or with wireless?

Comment: @user270189 Ok, is it possible to connect this computer to the internet with a wired connection?  Typically, when Ubuntu is in a partially working state like this, it will not connect to wifi but will easily connect to a wired network.  An internet connection is required for this operation to work.

Comment: @user270189 Without Internet, the only other possibility I'm aware of is to upgrade using an alternate install ISO, but it requires a bit more terminal work.  Instructions: http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-using-alternate.html  Otherwise, I think you'll have to back up your files and clean install.

Comment: @user270189 I edited and added another possible solution, so try that first.

Comment: Ugh, I hate to have this long discussion in the comments section but it doesn't seem like you can use chat yet.  Anyway, here are instructions on creating a CD: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto